# How to resize divs based on how many divs are displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction here, basically i am trying to make it so the boxes will resize themself to always be able to display all of the boxes without making the user scroll down. So regardless of their resoulution it will always neatly display all boxes, I intend to add a button to allow another sitebox to be added into the siteBoxHolder so it needs to be dynamic and always fit onto one screen without scrolling is this posible?

At the moment I have set the boxes to a percentage of the screen, but i presume i may need to use js to get the number of divs active and then use division? But since i need them spaced evenly i'm unsure what the best way is. I feel like i should just be able to use css to achieve this.

here's what i have so far.. https://jsfiddle.net/50bLsc3a/

Here's hoping someone can help. Thanks.

Code:

```css
.siteBox
{
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 20%;
 margin: 1.7%;
}
HTML, BODY
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.siteBoxHolder
{
 margin: 20px;
}
.siteBoxImage
{
 width: 90%;
}
.siteTitle
{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="siteBoxHolder">
        

  <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

  

  

 </div>
 

</body>
```

Comment: I did a [memory game](http://js-adventures.netne.net/Mememory/Mememory.html) that scales every piece (div) dynamically according to screen / browser size. I don't have time right now to post the code, but you can see it in the source.

Comment: Thanks checking it out now.

Comment: Have you got any problem with using flexbox? Check out this [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for browser compatibility information.

Comment: I agree with @jaunt . The quickest solution would indeed be flex box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. I used this tutorial to and it is a really good tutorial.

Comment: nice flexbox is way more compatible now, But it's been so long. Would you have a suggestion using flexbox?

Comment: @Vinc199789 thanks i shall check it out now. How would this go when there is a button that removes or adds divs?

Comment: Actually flex is awesome, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with simple flex box...THanks @Vinc199789

```css
.siteBox
{
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 20%;
 margin: 1.7%;
}
.siteBoxHolder
{
 margin: 20px;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.siteBoxImage
{
 width: 90%;
}
.siteTitle
{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
 <title>Custom Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="siteBoxHolder">
        

  <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

       <div class="siteBox">
            

   <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" class="siteBoxImage"></a>
                
   <h1 class="siteTitle">Title</h1>

       </div>

  

  

 </div>
 

</body>

</html>
```